# XSLT - How To Split an Attribute Value into 2 attributes

Tags: xml, transform, xslt-1.0

I have an XML document that I want to extract certain values from, one of which is a Pipe separated value. I'm trying to take this pipe separated value and turn it into two attributes... I was hoping someone with more familiarity with xml transforms can help...

Here is my XML:

```
<XML>
  <FXTRANSACTION QUANTITY="1291.03" >
    <INTERFACE TEMPLATEID="FX" />
    <WORKFLOWPROCESSING STPAUTHORIZE="TRUE" />
    <FXLEG LEGID="1" CUSTOMERID="|C|A|B"/>
  </FXTRANSACTION>
</XML>
```

What I'd like to transform this into is:

```
<XML Quantity="1291.03" TemplateId="FX" STPAUTHORIZE="TRUE" LEGID="1" CUSTOMERID1="A" CUSTOMERID1="B" CUSTOMERID1="C" LEGID="1">
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I can't seem to create the right transform which will both extract the values I need as well as split my CustomerId attribute.

Thanks for taking the time to look

Comment: Your result XML isn't well-formed, it contains multiple attributes with the same name: `CUSTOMERID1`. Attribute name must be unique.

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT 1.0 you need a recursive template to do this. Fortunately it already exists. Go to www.exslt.org and look for the str:tokenize template.